# Background Gradient Effect Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gradient

How can I achieve this gradient background effect in Flutter?

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4IVH.jpg)

I am working on this as part of a school project but I am relatively new to coding so I am really struggling. Please help.

Comment: just google "gradient flutter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: [List of Your Colors]
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Wissame Sbenaty, I have worked on gradient before but I was specifically looking to achieve the same effect as in the image. Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: @SPLee ah ok
i think you should use a color picker and select the corner's color  " top right and bottom left" 
this should be enough to describe the gradient correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end: Alignment.centerRight,
      colors: [
        Color(0xff147EFF),
        Color(0xff6236BE)
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Add your colors :)

Here more info -> [LinearGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html)